# Jquery - Select Element Using String

Tags: javascript, jquery

So here is my code, if a window is closing, which will trigger the function given the class name `.window` and the unique window name, which is prepared for each of the different functions windows. The function is going to find the `.taskbar-icon` with the same unique name as the window and remove the class `.active`, to tell the user that the window is in fact closed.

The unique names of the windows are given by me and there should be only one unique window as a time, meaning there should not be 2 elements with the same unique class name, e.g. `.window.q`

```
function disappearWindow(target) {
    if(target.hasClass("q")) {
        $(".taskbar-icon.q").removeClass("active");
    }
    if(target.hasClass("f")) {
        $(".taskbar-icon.f").removeClass("active");
    }
}

disappearWindow($(".window.q"));
```

As you can see above, each time I insert a new window, I would give it a class name such as `q`or `ts` etc, than using the code above, I would have to add another statement, with is not productive and wastes resources.

The windows should only contain the classes `window THE_ACTUAL_UNIQUE_NAME ui-draggable ui-resizable`.

So I would like something like this:

```
function disappearWindow(target) {
    $(".taskbar-icon" + NAME_FROM_FUNCTION_CALLING).removeClass("active");
}
```

Is there a way to extract the name out so the code above can be less "hacky" and more friendly? Or any advices to do something else to achieve the same result?

I don't mind changing the names.

Comment: How many names (potentially), and do you know what they'll be in advance, or is it dynamic in some way?

Comment: I guess I'm confused why you can't just write $(".taskbar-icon").removeClass("active")?

Comment: sorry, have many taskbar-icons, will edit now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking and exactly got your point, I think the following code should work.

```
function disappearWindow(selectorStr) {
    var activeClass     = selectorStr.substr( selectorStr.lastIndexOf(".") + 1 );
    var targetElemStr   = ".taskbar-icon." + activeClass;
    $(targetElemStr).removeClass("active");
}

disappearWindow(".window.q");
```

Comment: Thank you, that even makes me have to type less jquery dollar signs :D

Comment: Just curious, can you turn $(".something") into a string, or extract all the classes of that element and form a string?

Comment: Thanks to you too Daniel, I actually get failed in converting a selector's result to string. However you can iterate over the resultant array to get the desired string.